# Accessing a field in an exception

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to have more information thrown as an Exception in kotlin?

```
data class ExceptionDetail(
    val thrownBy: String,
    val calculationStage: Int,
    val code: Int = 0,
    val message: String = "",
)
```

now in my custom exception

```
class CustomException(message: ExceptionDetail? = null, cause: Throwable? = null) : Exception(
    message?.errorMessage,
    cause,
) {
    constructor(cause: Throwable) : this(null, cause)
}
```

after I throw it, how can I get details of the exception:

```
throw CustomException(ExceptionDetail(thrownBy = "inner", calculationStage = 9))
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the extra field in your Exception class:

```
class CustomException(val detail: ExceptionDetail? = null, cause: Throwable? = null) : Exception(
    detail?.message,
    cause,
)
```

Then you can access it in  a catch block:

```
catch (e: CustomException) {
  e.detail
}
```